# Multiple website custom magento php code

Tags: magento

I have 9 websites in my magento installation, which again then have multiple languages etc. like below:

```
US - English
US - Spanish
US - French
UK - English
FR - French
```

I have created a php file with custom code which exports orders of websites. And those needs to be stored in separate folders based on country.

I want to run my export file url like http://example.com/xml/export.php?website=us

But to get the orders from a particular website, I need to set the `Mage:app` properly for that I have used below code:

`Mage::app('base_uk', 'website');`

But the above code is not working, and it is always fetching the orders from US store only, which is default for `Mage:app()`.

How can I set my code to fetch orders form a specific website?

Please help, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For Product collections there is such a thing as ->setStoreFilter($store_id). Since each $store_id is unique for any given website (i.e. if you know the $store_id, you know the $website_id), you might use this.

Sample code:

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect("*")
    ->addStoreFilter($store_id)
```

My two cents: run that code for all $store_ids within the desired $website_id.

Note: I did not test this, just thinking with you. Could be that this function is not available for order collections. I still think you should then try to find a function that does filter orders by $store_id, since that is the Magento way to go!